# Cómo adaptar animación en mensaje de respuesta de AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Os vengo a molestar tengo la siguiente animación que desaparece en `x` segundos, pero no se está validando el cierre **[x]** quiero dar la posibilidad de cerrar el mensaje manualmente, pero no me está funcionando.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.response').fadeIn(500).delay(6000).fadeOut(500);
    $(".dismiss").click(function(){
       $(".response").fadeOut(500);
});
});
```

```css
.response {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0.9;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="response">
  <span class="dismiss">X</span>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas non.</p>
</div>
```

**El error**

Al adaptar la animación a la respuesta de `AJAX` de la siguiente manera el `div` de la animación se ejecuta automáticamente al refrescar la página o abrir directamente la página y no debe hacer así debido a que este se debe ejecutar solo si se recibe una petición o respuesta por medio de `ajax`

**Ejemplo:**

> Este es mi `AJAX` tomando ejemplos en la siguiente [fuente endeos](https://blog.endeos.com/usando-ajax-con-php-y-jquery/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.response').fadeIn(500).delay(6000).fadeOut(500);
    $(".dismiss").click(function(){
       $(".response").fadeOut(500);
});
});
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('submit', '#post', function() {
      var data = $(this).serialize();
      $.ajax({          
        type : 'POST',
        url  : 'post.php',
        data : data,
        success :  function(data) {                 
          $(".response").html(data);       
        }
      });         
      return false;         
    });
  });
```

Y obtengo respuesta

```
<div class="response"><!-- Respuesta AJAX --></div>';
```

Comment: Mi pregunta es lo qe tu deseas es que al darle click a la x se cierre el mensaje de alerta cierto?

Comment: @Mariano El `div` de la respuesta quiero que aparezca el error o la respuesta de la misma forma como se ejecuta el primer código es decir que desaparezca el mensaje por determinado `x` segundos y a la vez dar la posibilidad de cerrar el mensaje manualmente **[x]** ***a eso se refería?***

Comment: @Mariano se refiere a esto `<div class="response"><!-- Respuesta AJAX --></div>';` ? Si es eso es la respuesta que emite `ajax` desde su función `$(".response").html(data);`  puede ser diferente mensajes de respuesta, no comprendo aún que debo aclarar :)

Comment: @Mariano Ahora he editado mi pregunta aclarando los errores del mismo, espero poder haber aclarado...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando invocas `delay` sobre un elemento, éste afecta a toda su cola de animaciones. El `fadeOut` que intentas llamar manualmente con la **X** no se ejecuta de inmediato sino que entra a la cola que está esperando por el término de delay.

Lo óptimo sería poder cancelar el delay cuando presiones **X** e interrumpir ese período de espera... lo malo es que `delay` no se puede cancelar [según la documentación](https://api.jquery.com/delay/):

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery
>   effects. Because it is limited —**it doesn't, for example, offer a way to
>   cancel the delay**— .delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native
>   setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use
>   cases.

Por lo mismo, hagámosle caso a la documentación y usemos `setTimeout` para lograr el comportamiento deseado:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.response').fadeIn(500);
    
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      $('.response').fadeOut(500);
    },6000);
    
    $(".dismiss").click(function(){
       $(".response").fadeOut(500);
    });
    
   
});
```

```css
.response {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0.9;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="response">
  <span class="dismiss">X</span>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas non.</p>
</div>
```

Para tu caso de uso sería mejor meter toda la animación dentro de la respuesta al post, porque de lo contrario pareciera que estás suponiendo que a lo más la respuesta demorará 6 segundos. Si demora 10 segundos, tu `fadeOut` impedirá que se muestre nada.

Segundo, si metes la respuesta en `$('.response')` desaparecerá la **X** y ya no podrás ocultar el div. Sería mejor que la respuesta fuera en el hijo `p` de `$('.response')`.

Yo aplicaría el `fadeIn` justo antes de gatillar la petición, aprovechando de modificar el mensaje que contiene:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".dismiss").click(function () {
        $(".response").fadeOut(500);
    });

    $(document).on('submit', '#post', function () {

        var data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'post.php',
            data: data,
            beforeSend: function () {
                $(".response").fadeIn(200);
            },
            success: function (response) {
                $(".response").html(response);
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    $('.response').fadeOut(500);
                }, 6000);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

});
```

Y de paso, contemplaría el caso de que la petición devolviera un error.

**EDIT**: intenté aplicar la respuesta a tu ejemplo en Ajax. Como ignoro si la pregunta original y la situación real tienen la misma estructura,terminé omitiendo el hecho de que llenar el DIV con la respuesta va a sobreescribir la X.

Comment: El código `ajax` que has proporcionado no me emite ninguna respuesta, no funciona.

Comment: Puede que la parte del ajax necesite usar `beforeSend` para mostrar el div de la respuesta. Pero esa es una parte complementaria. Tu pregunta original era por qué la X no ocultaba el div y te mostré que era a causa del delay. Voy a modificar la respuesta para usar `beforeSend`, pero no tengo cómo probarla usando los snippers de StackOverflow

Comment: Sigue lo mismo no emite ninguna respuesta, el editor sublime text me marca de color rojo esto `)`  del último cierre `});`

Comment: Tienes razón, ese cierre está de más. Acabo de quitarlo

Comment: funciona pero queda activado una notificación toca darle click en la **[x]** para que cierre ese aviso y no debería mostrase esa notificación por que no se a ejecutado `ajax` solo cuando `ajax` reciba algún error debe mostrarse, no se si puedas observar algo como referencia de [esto](https://jsfiddle.net/ntck49q3/) y  [esto](http://www.webslesson.info/2017/05/facebook-style-popup-notification-using-php-ajax-bootstrap.html)

Comment: Explicó la aplicación, tengo el formulario con un `input` donde se inserta un código de trabajador, y el botón tipo `submit` al enviar ese dato `ajax` me imite una respuesta ejemplo ese código de trabajador no existe, y si se envía los campos vacíos emite un mensaje debes introducir un código de trabajador etc...

Comment: En resúmen la petición de Ajax depende del envío de datos del botón type `submit` más tomando referencia de que formulario es: `#post`

Comment: Todo eso que me describes se aparta de la pregunta inicial. Espero que puedas encontrar una solución integral al problema. Ya te ayudé en todo lo que estaba en la pregunta original y más

Comment: solo mencioné como una referencia... La pregunta dice como adaptar la animación a `ajax` ????

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esto:

Dentro de la etiqueta `a` agregale el atributo `href="#"`

También al ejecutar el evento click en el div, puedes ocultar el span de esta manera:

```
$(".n2").hide();
```