# ¿Cómo actualizar código jQuery a la nueva versión y solucionar error en editar usuario - ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, html5, ajax, css3

Tengo realizado un pequeño script de un popup modal box jQuery.

Pero observó que en la nueva versión jQuery existen nuevos cambios, código que ya está obsoleto, cómo puedo actualizar `jQuery 2.1` a la versión `jQuery 3.2.1` utilizando los nuevos métodos de respuesta ajax `done` y `fail` en vez del antiguo uso `success`

Ahora en mi código tengo problemas en editar los datos del usuario, cuando edito los datos del usuario en vez de actualizar los datos del usuario editado lo que hace es agregar un nuevo usuario en vez de actualizarlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## Código ajax Popup Modal Box

```js
$(function() {
  //----- OPEN
  $('[data-modal-open]').on('click', function(e)  {
    $('#insert_form')[0].reset();
    var targeted_modal_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-modal-open');

    $('[data-modal="' + targeted_modal_class + '"]').fadeIn(350);
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  //----- CLOSE
  $('[data-modal-close]').on('click', function(e)  {
    var targeted_modal_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-modal-close');
    $('[data-modal="' + targeted_modal_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);

    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
  $(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#add').click(function(){  

                     $('#employee_id').val("");
           $('#insert_form')[0].reset();  
      });  
      $(document).on('click', '.edit_data', function(){ 

           var employee_id = $(this).attr("id");  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"fetch.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{employee_id:employee_id},  
                dataType:"json",  
                success:function(data){  
                     $('#name').val(data.name);  
                     $('#address').val(data.address);  
                     $('#gender').val(data.gender);  
                     $('#designation').val(data.designation);  
                     $('#age').val(data.age);  
                     $('#employee_id').val(data.id);  
                     $('#insert').val("Update");  
                     $('[data-modal="add_data_modal"]').fadeIn(350);

      
                }  
           });  
      });  
      $('#insert_form').on("submit", function(event){  
           event.preventDefault();  

            $('[data-modal="add_data_modal"]').fadeOut(350);
      
           if($('#name').val() == "")  
           {  
                alert("Name is required");  
           }  
           else if($('#address').val() == '')  
           {  
                alert("Address is required");  
           }  
           else if($('#designation').val() == '')  
           {  
                alert("Designation is required");  
           }  
           else if($('#age').val() == '')  
           {  
                alert("Age is required");  
           }  
           else  
           {  
                $.ajax({  
                     url:"insert.php",  
                     method:"POST",  
                     data:$('#insert_form').serialize(),  
                     beforeSend:function(){  
                          $('#insert').val("Inserting");  
                     },  
                     success:function(data){  
                         
                          $('#insert_form')[0].reset();  
                              $('[data-modal="add_data_modal"]').fadeOut(350);

                          $('#employee_table').html(data);  
                     }  
                });  
           }  
      });  
      $(document).on('click', '.view_data', function(){  
           var employee_id = $(this).attr("id");  
           if(employee_id != '')  
           {  
                $.ajax({  
                     url:"select.php",  
                     method:"POST",  
                     data:{employee_id:employee_id},  
                     success:function(data){
                            $('[data-modal="empdetail"]').fadeIn(350);
                            $('#employee_detail').html(data);  
      
                     }  
                });  
           }            
      });  
 });
```

```css
.content {
 max-width:800px;
 width:100%;
 margin:0px auto;
 margin-bottom:60px;
}

/* Outer */
.modal {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 display:none;
 position:fixed;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 99999;
}

/* Inner */
.modal-inner {
 width: 500px;
 position: relative;
 margin: 10% auto;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background: #fff;
}

/* Close Button */
.modal-close {
 width:30px;
 height:30px;
 padding-top:4px;
 display:inline-block;
 position:absolute;
 top:0px;
 right:0px;
 transition:ease 0.25s all;
 -webkit-transform:translate(50%, -50%);
 transform:translate(50%, -50%);
 border-radius:1000px;
 background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 font-family:Arial, Sans-Serif;
 font-size:20px;
 text-align:center;
 line-height:100%;
 color:#fff;
}

.modal-close:hover {
 -webkit-transform:translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
 transform:translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
 background:rgba(0,0,0,1);
 text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" style="width:700px;">  
                <h3 align="center">PHP Ajax Update MySQL Data Through Bootstrap Modal</h3>  
                <br />  
                <div class="table-responsive">  
                     <div align="right">  
                          <button type="button" name="add" id="add" data-toggle="modal" data-modal-open="add_data_modal" class="btn btn-warning">Add</button>  
                     </div>  
                     <br />  
                     <div id="employee_table">  
                          <table class="table table-bordered">  
                               <tr>  
                                    <th width="70%">Employee Name</th>  
                                    <th width="15%">Edit</th>  
                                    <th width="15%">View</th>  
                               </tr>  
                                <?php  
                               while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                               ?>  
                               <tr>  
                                    <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>  
                                    <td><input type="button" name="edit" value="Edit" id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs edit_data" /></td>  
                                    <td><input type="button" name="view" value="view" id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs view_data" /></td>  
                               </tr>  
                               <?php  
                               }  
                               ?>    
                          </table>  
                     </div>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>  
  
<div id="dataModal" class="modal" data-modal="empdetail">  
      <div class="modal-inner">  
           <div class="modal-content">  
                <div class="modal-header">  
                      <a class="modal-close" data-modal-close="empdetail" href="#">x</a>
                     <h4 class="modal-title">Employee Details</h4>  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-body" id="employee_detail">  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-footer">  
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-modal-close="empdetail">Close</button> 

                </div>  
           </div>  
      </div>  
 </div>  
 <div id="add_data_Modal" class="modal"  data-modal="add_data_modal">  
      <div class="modal-inner">  
           <div class="modal-content">  
                <div class="modal-header">  
                      <a class="modal-close" data-modal-close="add_data_modal" href="#">x</a>

                     <h4 class="modal-title">PHP Ajax Update MySQL Data Through Bootstrap Modal</h4>  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-body">  
                     <form method="post" id="insert_form">  
                          <label>Enter Employee Name</label>  
                          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" />  
                          <br />  
                          <label>Enter Employee Address</label>  
                          <textarea name="address" id="address" class="form-control"></textarea>  
                          <br />  
                          <label>Select Gender</label>  
                          <select name="gender" id="gender" class="form-control">  
                               <option value="Male">Male</option>  
                               <option value="Female">Female</option>  
                          </select>  
                          <br />  
                          <label>Enter Designation</label>  
                          <input type="text" name="designation" id="designation" class="form-control" />  
                          <br />  
                          <label>Enter Age</label>  
                          <input type="text" name="age" id="age" class="form-control" />  
                          <br />  
                          <input type="hidden" name="employee_id" id="employee_id" />  
                          <input type="submit" name="insert" id="insert" value="Insert" class="btn btn-success" />  
                     </form>  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-footer">  
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-modal-close="add_data_modal" href="#">Close</button>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </div>  
 </div>
```

Comment: Los modal que estas implementando son una funcionalidad que trae boostrap en su codigo, al desactivarlo claramente **dejara de funcionar**, si deseas implementar uno por tu cuenta **te recomendo el codigo** de este sitio: [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp)

Comment: @A.Cedano Edite nuevamente mi pregunta, se han realizado varias ediciones debido que a poco a poco fui solucionando los problemas, pero existe un solo problema en el código ajax que es al editar el usuario, en vez de editar sus datos al actualizarlos lo que hace es añadir un nuevo registro y eso no debe suceder, el otro detalle es el de actualizar a la nueva versión de jQuery usando sus nuevos complementos `done` y `fail` en vez de `success`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Su código Jquery complementando con el de está [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/128157/c%C3%B3mo-insertar-datos-y-actualizar-datos-en-sentencias-preparas-mysqli-orientados/128165#128165) parece que el error es claro, siempre envía el `form` del modal al mismo archivo `php` pero su validación para saber que operación realizar es

```
if($_POST["employee_id"] != '')  { ...}
```

Pero su método `ajax`  seguro **siempre** envía el valor en blanco y no ingresa al `if` , el campo está oculto pero lo envía y lo llena en este método. Debería verificar los datos que retorna `fetch.php` sí está el atributo `id` si no está, debería agregar  a su consulta `select`.

Luego de solucionar el primer punto , Para migrar su código a Jquery V3, las partes más esenciales que se podría modificar es la verificación del `ready` del documento

Anteriormente se realizaba con

```
$(document).ready(function($) {

});
```

Debería modificar y trabajar de la siguiente forma

```
$(function() {

});
```

Para la función `Ajax` se debería reemplazar el `success` y `error` por `done` y `fail` además de existir `always` que se **ejecutará siempre**, estos tienen la siguiente estructura , en la sección del `fail` la variable `jqxhr` será un objeto con sus propiedades donde por ejemplo está `responseXML y/ o responseText` cuando se responde `XML` o Texto directamente.

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'script.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {name: 'Nombre'},
    })
    .done(function() {
        console.log("Correcto");
    })
    .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
        console.log(jqXHR.responseText);//Posible Texto Error
        console.log("Request failed: " + textStatus );
    }).always(function() {
        console.log("complete");
    });
});
```

Esta claro que en los ejemplos estos métodos son llamados directamente con `.método(function()){...}` pero también se podría tener en una variable la llamada `ajax` y llamar estos métodos directamente desde dicha variable.

```
$(function() {
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: 'script.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {name: 'Nombre'},
    });


    request.done(function() {
        console.log("Correcto");
    })

    request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
        console.log(jqXHR.responseText);//Posible Texto Error
        console.log("Request failed: " + textStatus );
    })

    request.always(function() {
        console.log("complete");
    });
});
```

Para su código, las modificaciones harían que su código tenga el siguiente formato

```js
$(function() {
    //----- OPEN
    $('[data-modal-open]').on('click', function(e)  {
        $('#insert_form')[0].reset();
        var targeted_modal_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-modal-open');

        $('[data-modal="' + targeted_modal_class + '"]').fadeIn(350);
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    //----- CLOSE
    $('[data-modal-close]').on('click', function(e)  {
        var targeted_modal_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-modal-close');
        $('[data-modal="' + targeted_modal_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);

        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#add').click(function(){  
        $('#employee_id').val("");
        $('#insert_form')[0].reset();  
    });  
    $(document).on('click', '.edit_data', function(e){ 
       var employee_id = $(this).attr("id");  
       $.ajax({  
            url:"fetch.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{employee_id:employee_id},  
            dataType:"json"
       }).done(function(data){
            $('#name').val(data.name);  
            $('#address').val(data.address);  
            $('#gender').val(data.gender);  
            $('#designation').val(data.designation);  
            $('#age').val(data.age);  
            $('#employee_id').val(data.id);  
            $('#insert').val("Update");  
            $('[data-modal="add_data_modal"]').fadeIn(350);
       });
    });  

    $("#insert_form").submit(function(e){
       event.preventDefault();  

        $('[data-modal="add_data_modal"]').fadeOut(350);

       if($('#name').val() == "")  
       {  
            alert("Name is required");  
       }  
       else if($('#address').val() == '')  
       {  
            alert("Address is required");  
       }  
       else if($('#designation').val() == '')  
       {  
            alert("Designation is required");  
       }  
       else if($('#age').val() == '')  
       {  
            alert("Age is required");  
       }  
       else  
       {  
            e.preventDefault();
            var name = $('#nombre').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'insert.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('#insert_form').serialize(),
                beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
                   $('#insert').val("Inserting");
                }
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                $('#insert_form')[0].reset();  
                $('[data-modal="add_data_modal"]').fadeOut(350);
                $('#employee_table').html(data); ;
            }).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
                console.log(jqXHR.responseText);//Posible Texto Error
                console.log("Request failed: " + textStatus );
            })
       } 
    }); 
    $(document).on('click', '.view_data', function(e){  
       var employee_id = $(this).attr("id");  
       if(employee_id != '')  
       {  
            $.ajax({  
                 url:"select.php",  
                 method:"POST",  
                 data:{employee_id:employee_id}
            }).done(function(data){
                $('[data-modal="empdetail"]').fadeIn(350);
                $('#employee_detail').html(data);  
            });
       }  
    });
});
```

> Para más detalle sobre `Jquery 3` y sus novedades, [puede revisar esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/51533/cu%C3%A1les-son-las-novedades-y-las-ventajas-de-jquery-3)

Comment: La función `fail` en su código que función cumple, porque no funciona como la respuesta de IniDesing si los archivos ajax php no están llamado muestra un error, pero en el caso de su código no es así no muestra el dialogo de advertencia al no estar llamando los archivos php...

Comment: o los errores al no llamar los archivos php en la ruta correctamente en vez de mostrarlo en una ventana de alerta, lo muestra por medio de la `console` al inspeccionar, así funciona su código?

Comment: Así es. Los mensajes se muestran en consola. Está claro que si hubo un error e ingresa al `fail` y puede mostrar el mensaje de alerta pero no siempre será el mismo error. Por eso especifique del objetivo jqXHR.

Comment: ah ya comprendo, comprendido :)

Answer (score 2):

Realmente no es tan difícil realizar la migración, realmente se debe tener en cuenta ciertos procedimientos sencillos que están enlazados casi al mismo código a diferencia que solo cambian los nombres.

Esto puede verificar desde la página oficial [jQuery & Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

> Deprecation Notice: The `jqXHR.success()`, `jqXHR.error()`, and `jqXHR.complete()` callbacks are removed as of `jQuery 3.0`. You can use `jqXHR.done()`, `jqXHR.fail()`, and `jqXHR.always()` instead.

En SO existen preguntas basadas al tema que puede servir, para seguir estudiando sus procedimientos:

- [¿Cuáles son las novedades y las ventajas de jQuery 3?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/51533/cu%C3%A1les-son-las-novedades-y-las-ventajas-de-jquery-3)
- [¿Cual es la diferencia entre success y done?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/98884/cual-es-la-diferencia-entre-success-y-done)

Existen otras preguntas que toman el tema, puede ser de gran utilidad enlazarlas más que todo para ver sus ejmplos de uso.

- [Cómo adaptar animación en mensaje de respuesta de AJAX](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/120743/c%C3%B3mo-adaptar-animaci%C3%B3n-en-mensaje-de-respuesta-de-ajax)
- [¿Cómo saber que valor se envió de un input/form AJAX?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/121052/c%C3%B3mo-saber-que-valor-se-envi%C3%B3-de-un-input-form-ajax)

Finalmente el código quedaría así utilizando los nuevos métodos `done` y `fail`, cabe recalcar que solo he realizado esos cambios.

Usted debe realizar lo siguiente el `document.ready` reemplazar por:

```
$(function() {
  //document.ready es obsoleto desde jQuery 3
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  //----- OPEN
  $('[data-modal-open]').on('click', function(e)  {
    $('#insert_form')[0].reset();
    var targeted_modal_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-modal-open');

    $('[data-modal="' + targeted_modal_class + '"]').fadeIn(350);
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  //----- CLOSE
  $('[data-modal-close]').on('click', function(e)  {
    var targeted_modal_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-modal-close');
    $('[data-modal="' + targeted_modal_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);

    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
  $(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#add').click(function(){  

                     $('#employee_id').val("");
                     $('#insert').val("Insert");
           $('#insert_form')[0].reset();  
      });  
      $(document).on('click', '.edit_data', function(){ 

           var employee_id = $(this).attr("id");  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"fetch.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{employee_id:employee_id},  
                dataType:"json"})  
                .done(function(data){  
                     $('#name').val(data.name);  
                     $('#address').val(data.address);  
                     $('#gender').val(data.gender);  
                     $('#designation').val(data.designation);  
                     $('#age').val(data.age);  
                     $('#employee_id').val(data.id);  
                     $('#insert').val("Update");  
                     $('[data-modal="add_data_modal"]').fadeIn(350);

      
                }).fail(function() {
        alert( "Ajax Request fail" );
      })

            
      });  
      $('#insert_form').on("submit", function(event){  
           event.preventDefault();  

            
           if($('#name').val() == "")  
           {  
                alert("Name is required");  
           }  
           else if($('#address').val() == '')  
           {  
                alert("Address is required");  
           }  
           else if($('#designation').val() == '')  
           {  
                alert("Designation is required");  
           }  
           else if($('#age').val() == '')  
           {  
                alert("Age is required");  
           }  
           else  
           {  
                $.ajax({  
                     url:"insert.php",  
                     method:"POST",  
                     data:$('#insert_form').serialize(), 
                     beforeSend:function(){  
                          $('#insert').val("Inserting");  
                     }
                     })  
                     .done(function(data){  
                         
                          $('#insert_form')[0].reset();  
                              $('[data-modal="add_data_modal"]').fadeOut(350);

                          $('#employee_table').html(data);      
                     })  
                     .fail(function() {
          alert( "Insert ajax request fail" );
          }) 
                  
                  
           }
      });  
      $(document).on('click', '.view_data', function(){  
           var employee_id = $(this).attr("id");  
           if(employee_id != '')  
           {  
                $.ajax({  
                     url:"select.php",  
                     method:"POST",  
                     data:{employee_id:employee_id}})  
                     .done(function(data){
                            $('[data-modal="empdetail"]').fadeIn(350);
                            $('#employee_detail').html(data);  
      
                     }) .fail(function() {
          alert( "Select ajax request fail" );
          }) 
                     
           }            
      });  
 });
```

```css
.content {
 max-width:800px;
 width:100%;
 margin:0px auto;
 margin-bottom:60px;
}

/* Outer */
.modal {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 display:none;
 position:fixed;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 99999;
}

/* Inner */
.modal-inner {
 width: 500px;
 position: relative;
 margin: 10% auto;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background: #fff;
}

/* Close Button */
.modal-close {
 width:30px;
 height:30px;
 padding-top:4px;
 display:inline-block;
 position:absolute;
 top:0px;
 right:0px;
 transition:ease 0.25s all;
 -webkit-transform:translate(50%, -50%);
 transform:translate(50%, -50%);
 border-radius:1000px;
 background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 font-family:Arial, Sans-Serif;
 font-size:20px;
 text-align:center;
 line-height:100%;
 color:#fff;
}

.modal-close:hover {
 -webkit-transform:translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
 transform:translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
 background:rgba(0,0,0,1);
 text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="container" style="width:700px;">  
                <h3 align="center">PHP Ajax Update MySQL Data Through Bootstrap Modal</h3>  
                <br />  
                <div class="table-responsive">  
                     <div align="right">  
                          <button type="button" name="add" id="add" data-toggle="modal" data-modal-open="add_data_modal" class="btn btn-warning">Add</button>  
                     </div>  
                     <br />  
                     <div id="employee_table">  
                          <table class="table table-bordered">  
                               <tr>  
                                    <th width="70%">Employee Name</th>  
                                    <th width="15%">Edit</th>  
                                    <th width="15%">View</th>  
                               </tr>  
                                <?php  
                               while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                               ?>  
                               <tr>  
                                    <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>  
                                    <td><input type="button" name="edit" value="Edit" id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs edit_data" /></td>  
                                    <td><input type="button" name="view" value="view" id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs view_data" /></td>  
                               </tr>  
                               <?php  
                               }  
                               ?>    
                          </table>  
                     </div>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>  
  
<div id="dataModal" class="modal" data-modal="empdetail">  
      <div class="modal-inner">  
           <div class="modal-content">  
                <div class="modal-header">  
                      <a class="modal-close" data-modal-close="empdetail" href="#">x</a>
                     <h4 class="modal-title">Employee Details</h4>  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-body" id="employee_detail">  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-footer">  
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-modal-close="empdetail">Close</button> 

                </div>  
           </div>  
      </div>  
 </div>  
 <div id="add_data_Modal" class="modal"  data-modal="add_data_modal">  
      <div class="modal-inner">  
           <div class="modal-content">  
                <div class="modal-header">  
                      <a class="modal-close" data-modal-close="add_data_modal" href="#">x</a>

                     <h4 class="modal-title">PHP Ajax Update MySQL Data Through Bootstrap Modal</h4>  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-body">  
                     <form method="post" id="insert_form">  
                          <label>Enter Employee Name</label>  
                          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" />  
                          <br />  
                          <label>Enter Employee Address</label>  
                          <textarea name="address" id="address" class="form-control"></textarea>  
                          <br />  
                          <label>Select Gender</label>  
                          <select name="gender" id="gender" class="form-control">  
                               <option value="Male">Male</option>  
                               <option value="Female">Female</option>  
                          </select>  
                          <br />  
                          <label>Enter Designation</label>  
                          <input type="text" name="designation" id="designation" class="form-control" />  
                          <br />  
                          <label>Enter Age</label>  
                          <input type="text" name="age" id="age" class="form-control" />  
                          <br />  
                          <input type="hidden" name="employee_id" id="employee_id" />  
                          <input type="submit" name="insert" id="insert" value="Insert" class="btn btn-success" />  
                     </form>  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-footer">  
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-modal-close="add_data_modal" href="#">Close</button>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </div>  
 </div>
```