# guardar dato de input en variable mediante javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Hola estoy haciendo un sistema de control de comedor pero tengo un problema, existe un input en el que se insertara el codigo de empleado mediante un lector de codigo de barras, pero no se como guardar esta informacion en una variable para mostrar los datos de el empleado que checo su tarjeta, mi codigo de busqueda es este:

```
$query_empresa=mysqli_query($con,"select * from empleados where no_emp='1'");
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($query_empresa);
```

en donde no_emp='1' deberia ir la variable insertada, alguien me podria explicar como guardar esta informacion mediante javascript? a continuacion mi codigo completo

```
<?php
/*-------------------------
Autor: INNOVAWEBSV
Web: www.innovawebsv.com
Mail: info@innovawebsv.com
---------------------------*/
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_login_status']) AND $_SESSION['user_login_status'] != 1) {
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
    }
require_once ("config/db.php");//Contiene las variables de configuracion para conectar a la base de datos
require_once ("config/conexion.php");//Contiene funcion que conecta a la base de datos
$active_facturas="active";
$active_productos="";
$active_clientes="";
$active_usuarios="";    
$title="Facturas | Simple Invoice";
$query_empresa=mysqli_query($con,"select * from empleados where no_emp='1'");
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($query_empresa);
?>
```

Configuración

```
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="row">

          <form class="form-horizontal" role="form"  id="datos_cotizacion">

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="q" class="col-md-2 control-label">Departamento o # de empleado</label>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="q" placeholder="Nombre del departamento # de empleado" onkeyup='load(1);'>
                        </div>



                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick='load(1);'>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" ></span> Buscar</button>
                            <span id="loader"></span>
                        </div>

                    </div>


        </form>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 " align="center"> 
            <div id="load_img">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $row['img_emp'];?>" alt="Logo">

            </div>
            <br>                
                <div class="row">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class=" col-md-9 col-lg-9 "> 
              <table class="table table-condensed">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <input type="hidden" name="id_perfil" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']?>">
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class='col-md-3'>No Emp:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="no_emp" value="<?php echo $row['no_emp']?>" required></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Nombre:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="nombre_emp" value="<?php echo $row['nombre_emp']?>" readonly></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Departamento:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="dep_emp" value="<?php echo $row['dep_emp']?>" readonly></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Confidencialidad:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="empresa_emp" value="<?php echo $row['empresa_emp']?>" readonly></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Fecha de Ingreso:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="fecha" value="<?php echo date('d-M-Y',strtotime($row['ing_emp'])) ?>" readonly></td>
                  </tr>



                </tbody>
              </table>


            </div>
            <div class='col-md-12' id="resultados_ajax"></div><!-- Carga los datos ajax -->
          </div>
        </div>



                        <button type="submit" class="hidden"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i> Actualizar datos</button>




      </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Osea quieres guardar el código del empleado en una variable javascript, registrarlo en la base de datos para posteriormente mostrarlo?, se un poco mas explicito.

Comment: es correcto, pero no para guardarlo en la base de datos si no para realizar una busqueda en la base de datos con el dato en el input

Comment: Para realizar una búsqueda en la base de datos no es necesario que guardes el valor del input en una variable js. Solo recuperas el valor que tenga el input con POST en php y con ese dato realizas la consulta. En tal caso que se necesite guardar un dato en una variable js seria para otras cosas, no para eso.

Comment: y como hago el post?

Comment: Para ello lo mejor sería usar Ajax. [Aquí tienes un ejemplo](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/6fju-td04) pulsa en **`Run - F9`** para verlo funcionando. La idea es la siguiente: toma un valor de un input en el formulario actual y a través de Ajax lo envía al servidor para hacer una consulta en base a ese valor. Si se tratase de una inserción o de una actualización el concepto sería el mismo. Lo interesante de Ajax es que puedes hacer esto de forma totalmente transparente y segura (aplicando consultas preparadas del lado de PHP claro está) sin tener que refrescar la página.

Comment: Puedes consultar [el apartado 4 de esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/128139/29967)  donde he explicado con detalle cómo funciona este código y allí puedes ver la parte de PHP que trabaja en *background*  en él, o sea, la parte que maneja el POST (o el GET) que envías desde Ajax al servidor.