# Php Mysql Según botón que se pulse registros que se muestran en la misma página

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Estoy  perdido con esto, el asunto es:

Tengo un archivo index.php que tiene, el siguiente formulario:

```
 <form action="siaradmin.php" method="POST"> 
        <select name="nivel" class="selectperso" placeholder="Buscar..">
            <option disabled selected>Elegí el nivel</option>
            <option value="ini">Inicial</option>
            <option value="prim">Primario</option>
            <option value="secu">Secundario</option>
            <option value="terc">Terciario</option>
            <option value="esp">Especial</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 persol">
        <select name="lenguaje"class="selectperso">
            <option disabled selected>Elegí el lenguaje</option>
            <option value="musica">Música</option>
            <option value="danza">Danza</option>
            <option value="artvis">Artes Visuales</option>
            <option value="teat">Teatro</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 persol">
        <select name="distrito" class="selectperso">
            <option disabled selected>Elegí el districto</option>
            <option value="puey">Gral Pueyrredon</option>
            <option value="alv">Gral Alvarado</option>
            <option value="marc">Mar chiquita</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 persol">
        <input class="boton4" type="submit" value="Vamos" id="vamos">
        </form>
```

Osea, según las opciones elegidas voy a siaradmin.php.

En siaradmin.php tengo:

```
<article class="normativas color1 col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-12 col-sm-4" id="normativas">   

    <li class="vertical"><a href="#"><h5>Normativas</h5></a></li>
    <li class="vertical"><a href="#"><h5>Documentos pedagógicos</h5></a></li>
    <li class="vertical"><a href="#"><h5>Documentos de sede</h5></a></li>
    <li class="vertical"><a href="#"><h5>Convocatorias</h5></a></li>
    <li class="vertical"><a href="#"><h5>Información</h5></a></li>
    <li class="vertical"><a href="#"><h5>Bibliografía</h5></a></li>
    <li class="vertical"><a href="#"><h5>Diseños curriculares</h5></a></li>
    <li class="vertical"><a href="#"><h5>Actividades</h5></a></li>
```

```
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 parrafo">

   <ul class="list-group">
     <?php
        $ultimo = "SELECT id,titulo,fecha,parrafo,archivo,lenguaje,nivel,distrito FROM comunica WHERE (lenguaje='$lenguaje' AND nivel='$nivel' AND distrito='$distrito') order by id desc";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($con,$ultimo);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
          ?>
                <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                  <?php echo $row['parrafo'];?>
                </li>
        <?php
          }
        ?>
     <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
     <span class="boton3">Cargar más</span>
```

La pregunta es cómo hago para que según la selección de una opción de los href en siaradmin.php recargue la página o muestre sin recargar aquellos registros que dentro de los ya mostrados cumplan con el criterio del href: por ejemplo si hace click en convocatorias muestre los registros que además de cumplir con nivel, lenguaje y distrito cumpla también con que destino = docped.

Agradecido de antemano, Saludos!

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow. Para esto tienes que usar Ajax. Aquí hay varios ejemplos de cómo hacerlo. [Este es un ejemplo en línea](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/6fju-td04) donde a partir de un ID se llena un formulario. El contexto de ese código se encuentra al final de [esta respuesta (ver el punto 4 de la misma con explicaciones detalladas que ayudan a entender cómo funciona Ajax)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/128139/29967).

Comment: Gracias y si tenías razón, de a poco iré elaborando la idea de ajax. Muchísimas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Algo asi te podria servir si deseas hacer un POST y quedarte en la misma pagina.

Primero en el forma action agrega `#` y en tu button submit agrega `name="send_form"`

```
<form action="#" method="POST"> 
     //SELECT
<input class="boton4" name="send_form" type="submit" value="Vamos" id="vamos">
 </form>


    <?php if (isset($_POST['send_form'])): ?>
    <?php include("siaradmin.php") ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: En realidad yo me quiero quedar en siaradmin.php y según lo que el usuario seleccione en los <li> recargar siaradmin.php con una nueva consulta que incluiría como parámetro el valor seleccionado por ejemplo: entro en siaradmin.php con nivel inicial lenguaje música y distrito Gral Pueyrredo mostrando todos los registros de la base de datos que coinciden con ese criterio, por eso el: $ultimo = "SELECT id,titulo,fecha,parrafo,archivo,lenguaje,nivel,distrito FROM comunica WHERE (lenguaje='$lenguaje' AND nivel='$nivel' AND distrito='$distrito') order by id desc";

Comment: Por ejemplo si el usuario pulsa en normativa: quiero mostrar $ultimo = "SELECT id,titulo,fecha,parrafo,archivo,lenguaje,nivel,distrito FROM comunica WHERE (lenguaje='$lenguaje' AND nivel='$nivel' AND distrito='$distrito' AND destino='normativa') order by id desc"; osea según lo que pulse realizar una nueva consulta sumando ese parámetro que me lo da lo que el alla pulsado

Answer (score 0):

segun lo que he visto de tu codigo y tu consulta, lo que no te funciona es el query

`$ultimo = "SELECT id,titulo,fecha,parrafo,archivo,lenguaje,nivel,distrito FROM comunica WHERE (lenguaje='$lenguaje' AND nivel='$nivel' AND distrito='$distrito') order by id desc";`

no veo donde has definido las variables $lenguaje, $nivel, $distrito por lo tanto estas estan sin datos.  debes recibir la informacion de esta manera $_POST['nivel'], $_POST['lenguaje'], $_POST['distrito '].

me dejas saber si esto resuelve tu consulta

Comment: En realidad no Kev, eso lo hacia previamente igual gracias por ayudar. La solución era ajax, estoy en los fundamentos pero de a poco iré hilando.